# Download an image From Craigslist

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlrequest

I have been trying to download an image from an url (Craigslist to be more exact)

Firstly I have used the SDWebImage framework and I could not see the images. After that I tried a simple method to download the url:

using this url for the image :

http://images.craigslist.org/01212_fxFfHsZFhoi_600x450.jpg

```
UIImageView image;
NSString *urlstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://images.craigslist.org/01212_fxFfHsZFhoi_600x450.jpg"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[image setImageWithURLRequest:request
              placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]
                       success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image){
                            // Succes on loading image
                       }
                       failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
                            // Fail to load image
                       }];
```

and I still can't see the image in my image view.

The problem is that if I change the url and use the same exact code, the image will be downloaded just fine. I tried to load the image in Safari and it works just fine, so the link is ok.

For example I used: 
http://monsieurstolli.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/meh.jpg

and it works.

I have no idea of how to download that image.

Edit:

I did a little more investigation and I changed the code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
    requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
    requestOperation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"];
    [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
        _imga.image = responseObject;

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Image error: %@", error);
    }];
    [requestOperation start];

    }
```

but this time I got the following error:

```
2014-10-16 15:07:10.537 CraigslistChecker[3192:907] Image error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: not found (404)" UserInfo=0x1c5b8e30 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x1c59ac60>, NSErrorFailingURLKey=images.craigslist.org/00W0W_blCL2sqk1Jt_600x450.jpg, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: not found (404), com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<0d0a>}
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x1c59b1f0
```

Comment: Please note the "Code snippet" button is for embedding JavaScript -- not for general code samples.  Use the "Code sample" button (Ctrl-K) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you posted returns a 404 (Not Found) error when I request it in a web browser, which means that the server is refusing to serve the URL to you.  So either:

- The URL is bogus
- The image URL was temporary (expiring) and went away before you requested it
- The image URL requires you to be logged in (and gives the wrong error code)
- The server prevents images from being loaded outside the context of a specific web page by checking the referrer.

My guess would be the last one.  If so, setting the "Referer" (misspelling intentional) header field on the NSURLRequest to the URL of a page that contains the image in question should fix the problem, but you should probably check with Craigslist to make sure that doing so won't be violating their terms of service.  Otherwise, there's a good chance that they'll blacklist your app's user agent string.